# Using a loop within a loop for numbering

Tags: r

I am trying to generate several lines of text with numbers changing sequentially changing at the end of the text. I am using a "    paste() " to write the text and trying to use a "    for loop    " to sequentially change numbers at the end of the text. Now, I want to write several hundreds of these lines so I am creating a list and trying populate the list. As an example, I would like to write this:

"

```
  $DATA ESTIM1101001.csv
  $DATA ESTIM1101002.csv
  .
  .
  .
  $DATA ESTIM11010020.csv

  $DATA ESTIM1102001.csv
  $DATA ESTIM1102002.csv
  $DATA ESTIM1102003.csv
  .
  .
  .
  $DATA ESTIM11020020.csv


  $DATA ESTIM11030001.csv
  $DATA ESTIM11030002.csv
  .
  .
  . 
  $DATA ESTIM110300020.csv
```

To elaborate, in  ESTIM110i00j.csv   i = 1 to 30   and j = 1 to 20
so 30*20= a total of 600 lines.

I am trying to do this by the code below:

```
b <- list()
for (i in 1:30) {
 for(j in 1:20) {
   for(p in 1:600){
b[[p]]<-(paste("$DATA",paste("ESTIM110",i,"00",j,".csv",sep=""),sep=" "))}}}
```

However, for all 600 lines I end up with $DATA ESTIM1010300020.csv . My suspicion is that I am not writing the for loop correctly to keep changing the numbers. I would greatly appreciate your help in clearly understanding the for loop to achieve this task. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your logic is a little bit off. It's looping through the `p` loop 600 times before it increments `i` or `j`. One way you could fix it is by adding a counter, like

```
b <- list()
count <- 1
for (i in 1:30) {
    for(j in 1:20) {
        b[[count]]<-(paste("$DATA",paste("ESTIM110",i,"00",j,".csv",sep=""),
            sep=" "))
        count <- count + 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a vectorized approach using `expand.grid` to find all the combos of your number sequences and `sprintf` to format the final string:

```
ids <- expand.grid(1:30, 1:20)
sprintf("$DATA ESTIM110%0d00%0d.csv", ids[,1], ids[,2])
```

Example output:

```
    > head(sprintf("$DATA ESTIM110%0d00%0d.csv", ids[,1], ids[,2]))
[1] "$DATA ESTIM1101001.csv" "$DATA ESTIM1102001.csv" "$DATA ESTIM1103001.csv" "$DATA ESTIM1104001.csv"
[5] "$DATA ESTIM1105001.csv" "$DATA ESTIM1106001.csv"
```